# Wordpress the_excerpt_rss filter not working on the 1st post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used 'the_excerpt_rss' filter to modify the feed's `<description>` tag content. Settings are kept to show most recent 20 items in syndication feed. Via Settings -> Reading -> 'Syndication feeds show the most recent' field. However, amongst the 20 listed post details the `<description>` tag content is not getting modified only for the 1st post content, whereas for the remaining 19 posts it is working fine.

Please guide, how to debug this issue/what could be the solution.